# Spring JPA 3.x JPQL group by entity must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I found a weird behavior and I wonder if I'm misusing JPA or if it's a Spring regression.

This is my entities :

```
@Entity
public class Brand {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Schema(description = "Brand's id", example = "1")
    private Long id;
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_brands", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brands_id"))
    private List<Brand> brands;
    // ...
}
```

I have this request :

```
@Query("select new com.mypackage.Statistic(br, count(p)) " +
        "from Lot l join l.products p join p.brands br " +
        "group by br " +
        "order by count(p) desc")
List<Statistic<Brand>> groupByProductBrand();
```

This was working fine in Spring Boot 2.5.4, then I updated to version 3.1.6 and now I got this error :

```
ERROR: column "b1_1.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function<EOL>
```

The request executed is :

```
select b1_1.id, ..., count(p1_0.products_id) 
from lot l1_0
join (lot_products p1_0 join product p1_1 on p1_1.id=p1_0.products_id) on l1_0.id=p1_0.lot_id 
join (product_brands b1_0 join brand b1_1 on b1_1.id=b1_0.brands_id) on p1_1.id=b1_0.product_id 
group by b1_0.brands_id 
order by count(p1_0.products_id) desc offset;
```

After some tests, with giving all the column names in select and group by clause, it appears than br.id from select is taken from the brands table (b1_1) but the br.id from group by is taken from the association table (b1_0). The value is obviously the same, but in this use case the sql query fails.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Hibernate?

Comment: Did you try replacing `group by br` with `group by br.id`?

Comment: I want to retrieve Statistic(b, count(p)), not Statistic(b.id, count(p)). So group by b.id doesn't work : ""b1_1.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function<EOL>"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must use a single valued path expression (or an identification variable) in your `group by` clause, which can be obtained using the `IN` keyword.

Try the following two queries (not sure which one would be syntactically correct, although I believe it should be the first one or both):

```
"select new com.mypackage.Statistic(br, count(p)) " +
    "from Lot l join l.products p, IN(p.brands) br " +
    "group by br " +
    "order by count(p) desc"
```

or

```
"select new com.mypackage.Statistic(br.brand, count(p)) " +
    "from Lot l join l.products p, IN(p.brands) br " +
    "group by br.brand " +
    "order by count(p) desc"
```